How to deploy built React app to find other pages by redirecting?
My web app is configured with React frontend and asp.net backend.
But to deploy this to aws ec2 instance, I've a little problem.
I'm now deploying react app using http-server and nginx on aws.
The routes are configured by this code.
<AlertProvider>
        <NavbarProvider>
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
                    <Route path="/signup" element={<Sign signUp />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Sign />} />
                    <Route path="/upload-portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
                    <Route path="/manage-users" element={<Manager />} />
                    <Route path="/manage-endpoints" element={<Manager />} />
                    <Route path="/manage-custom-nodes" element={<Manager />} />
                    <Route path="/manage-value-types" element={<Manager />} />
                    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </NavbarProvider>
    </AlertProvider>

And nginx configuration is as following
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Fontend proxies
    location /signup {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /upload-portfolio {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /manage-users {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /manage-endpoints {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /manage-custom-nodes {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /manage-value-types {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Backend proxies
    location /user {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /portfolio {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /category {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

But unfortunately, I can't find /login or /upload-portfolio page directly.
When I redirect using useNavigate hook, I can, but if I use window.href.url or find host/login, I can't find page.
If you have experience with it, I hope you help me.
Thank you.

I solved this problem.
This problem is ocurred in deploying single page web app.
I solved this problem using http-server-spa.
If you met similar problem, I think that it can help you.
Thank you.
